# Not printing array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just have no idea when I even do a test run of this controller it does not print the $user_data. I'm not seeing why it wouldn't. Does anyone else? Because clearly what I want to do is match the input with what is store in the database.

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Activate extends CI_Controller 
{ 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('kow_auth');            
}   

public function index($param1 = NULL, $param2 = NULL)
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '<script src="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/assets/js/activatevalidate.js"></script>';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    $x = 0;
    if(($param1 !== NULL)&&($param2 !== NULL))
    {

        //params not null yay..
        if((isset($param1))&&((trim($param1) !== '')||(!empty($param1))))
        {
            if(!is_numeric($param1))
            {
              $x++;
            } 
        }
        if((isset($param2))&&((trim($param2) !== '')||(!empty($param2))))
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $param2))
            {
              $x++;
            } 
        }


        if($x !== 0)
        {
           $bodyContent = "error_page";
        }
        else
        {
           $bodyContent = "activate_form";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $bodyContent = "error_page";
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function activate_submit()
{        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_id', 'User ID', 'trim|required|xss_clean|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('registration_key', 'Registration Key', 'trim|required|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!'));    
    }
    else
    {                           
        if ($this->kow_auth->activate_user($this->input->post('user_id'), $this->input->post('registration_key'), $this->input->post('password'))) 
        {
            echo json_encode(array('sucess' => 'yes', 'message' => 'Your account has been successfully activated!'));
        } 
        else 
        {                                                           
            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'yes', 'message' => 'The activation code you entered is incorrect or expired!'));
        }
    }
}

}

/* End of file activate.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/activate.php */
```

Library:

```
function activate_user($user_id, $registration_key, $password)
{
    $this->ci->users->purge_na();

    if ((strlen($user_id) > 0) AND (strlen($registration_key) > 0)) 
    {
        $user_data = $this->ci->users->get_user_by_user_id($user_id);
        print_r($user_data);
        $genPassHash = $this->ci->genfunc->GenPassHash($password);
        echo '<br />';
        print_r($genPassHash[0]);

        if ($user_data['password'] == $genPassHash[0])
        {
            return $this->ci->users->activate_user($user_id, $registration_key, $reGenFromPostPW[]);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;                
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong to not have it be printing the array out.

Comment: Which method of the controller are you running? What data are you passing in? Also, don't call parameters `$param1` and `$param2`, please please PLEASE give them meaningful names. If it contains an id, call it `$id`. If it contains an action, call it `$action`. Whatever, just give people an idea of what you expect `$param1` to be.

Comment: I'm calling the activate submit function in the controller for when I submit the form.  Here's the form: http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/activate/10000/9f5b8139fdb9c50543cdf916eb38f686

Comment: It prints the genPassHash[0] but doesn't even bother printing the $user_data array variable.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Its just deciding to not print the variable array. I echoed the user_id since it uses it and it echos right atleast but not sure if the function is actually running or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the purge_na function. It kept deleting the users including the one trying to activate before activating them.